# how to see the history of the events in the Event Grid Domain Topic?

Tags: azure, .net-core, azure-eventgrid

I have created Event Grid Domain along with Topic in azure. And then integrated the Azure Event Grid Viewer site under Event grid Subscription to see the events in real-time manner by following this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure-samples/azure-event-grid-viewer/azure-event-grid-viewer/). This site will allow you to see the event details in real-time manner. But I want to see the history of all events processed with in last day or week or month etc.

So, can anyone suggest me how to see the history of the events in the Event Grid Domain Topic?

Answer (score 1):

> So, can anyone suggest me how to see the history of the events in the Event Grid Domain Topic?

Basically, you can [subscribed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/event-domains#domain-scope-subscriptions) on the Event Domain with an event hub event handler destination to store all events.